# How can I slow down a loop in Python?

Tags: python

If I have a list l:

```
l = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Is there a way to control the following *for* loop so that the next element in the list is only printed one second after the previous?

```
for i in l:
    print i
```

In other words, is there a way to elegantly slow down a loop in Python?

Comment: That's funny, most people want to know how to _speed up_ their loops!

Comment: I find that running it on my old Treo 300 is a good way to slow down the loops…

Comment: More seriously, if you're trying to watch what's going on, you may want to try running in a debugger or an interactive visualizer, instead of just tossing in `sleep` calls.

Comment: How can slow be achieved without time.sleep? (Am on a platform that allows time but not sleep, a security fear with them). Pretty sure an inconsistency I'm seeing is from something asynchronous on the back end and I have no access and they're no help..I think the bug I'm seeing will disappear with slower execution.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use `time.sleep`

```
import time

for i in l:
    print i
    time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 10):

If you use `time.sleep(1)`, your loops will run a little over a second since the looping and printing also takes some time. A better way is to sleep for the remainder of the second. You can calculate that by using `-time.time()%1`

```
>>> import time
>>> L = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> for i in L:
...     time.sleep(-time.time()%1)
...     print i
...
```

It's easy to observe this by using `print i, repr(time.time())`

```
>>> for i in L:
...     time.sleep(-time.time()%1)
...     print i, repr(time.time())
... 
0 1368580358.000628
1 1368580359.001082
2 1368580360.001083
3 1368580361.001095
4 1368580362.001149
5 1368580363.001085
6 1368580364.001089
7 1368580365.001086
8 1368580366.001086
9 1368580367.001085
```

vs

```
>>> for i in L:
...     time.sleep(1)
...     print i, repr(time.time())
... 
0 1368580334.104903
1 1368580335.106048
2 1368580336.106716
3 1368580337.107863
4 1368580338.109007
5 1368580339.110152
6 1368580340.111301
7 1368580341.112447
8 1368580342.113591
9 1368580343.114737
```

Comment: Besides forcing this to align on the exact second mark, this also assumes that the cost of `time.time` and `time.sleep` is negligible, but the time of `print` is significant, and that `sleep` is accurate to the relevant scale, both of which are unlikely to be true on most platforms…

Comment: @abarnert, the time caused from `time.time()` and `time.sleep()` doesn't matter much as long as it's fairly consistent. `sleep()` doesn't offer a guarantee for precise timing anyway.

Comment: The second part of your comment is the main point. `sleep` isn't accurate or precise no matter what you do. It could easily sleep past the next `.000` mark, which means your code will lose a whole second, while the "dumb" code would just lose 50us. Is that really an improvement? You need more complicated logic (basically, keep track of the time to sleep _until_, so you can correct for oversleep) to actually do this right. There are very few situations where `sleep(1)` is not good enough, but `sleep(-time.time()%1)` is.

Comment: @abarnert, depends on the use case. If the code in the loop is more complicated than `print` and takes a substantial part of (but less than) a second, my version will run 3600 times an hour.

Answer (score 5):

You can pause the code execution using [`time.sleep`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.sleep):

```
import time

for i in l:
    print(i)
    time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the [`time.sleep`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.sleep) function.  Just do `time.sleep(1)` in your function.

Answer (score -6):

Use `time.sleep(number)`:

```
for i in range(i)
print(1)
time.sleep(0.05)
```

Comment: Necro-posting is fine, if it brings some additional value, but this answer brings no such light on the matter: the code doesn't even work.